# Grammar related questions

Tags: grammar

I am a little confused about these sentences. Would love to have your help. Thank you...

If possible then please tell then why the other option(s) isn't correct,

**Q1 - If you ____ you would succeed.**

a) works hard

*b) worked hard ( correct. But why? )*

c) had worked hard

d) work hard ( why this one isn't correct? )

My opinion: "would succeed" shows that the sentence isn't of past but is of future or present.. Therefore, I think it would make more sense to use "work hard" instead of "worked hard".

**Q2 - He cried as if he _____ mad.**

*a) had been ( correct. But why? )*

b) was ( why this one isn't correct? )

c) is

d) will be

My opinion: Shouldn't it be, "He cried as if he were mad"?

**Q3 - He ___ himself while running.**

a) hurted

b) had hurted

*c) hurt ( correct but why? )*

d) hurts ( why this one isn't correct? )

My opinion: Shouldn't be "hurts" more appropriate to use here? Or at least "He hurts himself while running" won't be wrong to use? It would mean that he always hurts himself whenever he runs. 
I think it would be better to choose "hurts" here instead of "hurt"...

**Q4 - He ______ to Paris tomorrow morning**

a) goes

b) is going ( why this one isn't correct? )

c) went

*d) will go ( correct )*

Suppose two men are talking about a third person. If first person wants to tell second person that the third person is leaving for Paris tomorrow then won't he say him that, "He's going to Paris tomorrow morning"?

Thanks a lot :) Will greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: This has the appearance of homework. In addition to highlighting your own selections, it would help for you to edit your question to say *why* you think your alternative answer is correct. (I agree with several of your alternatives.) I'll also note that **hurted* is *not* the past tense of *hurt*.

Comment: @Lawrence I have edited and have provided my opinion on every question in whatever way possible. I don't disagree with the correct options ( which I have mentioned ) though I think that other options are also correct, at least to some extent. And I want to know that are those really correct or am I wrong? If I am wrong then how?

Oh, yes, I didn't notice... Hurt is the 2nd and 3rd form of "hurt". Thank you.. 
I am a college student. This isn't really a homework. We have to deal with these sentences in our exam and these are few of the examples given in our book. I was confused about these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your opinions for Q1 (present tense) and Q2 ([subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)).

Q2 (b) can also be correct (see [this excerpt](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=olBgow5aJhAC&pg=PT182&lpg=PT182&dq=grammar%20%22as%20if%20he%20was%22&source=bl&ots=PckXgySUlq&sig=m2DCNmLEgy0ftrRat7LqgeudwGM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU4rOu94rMAhWFopQKHaj8B08Q6AEIXDAJ#v=onepage&q=grammar%20%22as%20if%20he%20was%22&f=false), item 10.4(5)).

Q3 - use (c) *hurt* if this happened in the past, but use (d) *hurts* if this happens on an ongoing basis as you suggest. (Compare it with "When he is free, he *donates* his time to charity.")

Q4 - it depends on the question.

- If asked, "When does he go to Paris?", say, "He goes ...".
- If asked, "When is he going to Paris?", say, "He is going ...".
- If asked, "When will he go to Paris?", say, "He will go ...".

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
Question 2, 
Actually, our problem is this that we have to choose only one option... Therefore, it is must for us to choose one option even if two of them are correct ( we will have to choose the one which is more appropriate/correct ). 
Therefore, I would like to ask you. Which option you would have selected? 

As of Question 3 and Question 4, they don't provide us any background ( like what person asked etc.... I just supposed that to give an example of what I was trying to say ). Same thing here, with which option you would have gone?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @AlexisEagle We don't normally do test answers on this site, but since you put in the effort to edit your question, here are some thoughts :) . I'd say 2b sounds more natural than 2a, 3c sounds less masochistic than 3d, and 4d simplistically references the future as opposed to the present, continuous or past tenses of 4a, 4b and 4c.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I greatly appreciate it :) 
This question can be closed. Thank you :)

Comment: @AlexisEagle You're welcome. :)